# ViewModel should never reference a view. If you do, then you'll get memory leaks. How to not violate this rule?

Tags: android, mvvm, memory-leaks, viewmodel

> A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that
> may hold a reference to the activity context.
>
> View model should never reference a view. If you do, then you'll get
> memory leaks.

[image]

```
public class FirstActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private int displayWidth;
    private int displayHeight;

    private double widthMultiplier;
    private double heightMultiplier;

    private int testedWidth = 1200;
    private int testedHeight = 1920;

    public void setDisplayCorrectedSizes(RelativeLayout relativeLayout){
        displayWidth = relativeLayout.getWidth();
        widthMultiplier = ((double) displayWidth) / ((double) testedWidth);

        displayHeight = relativeLayout.getHeight();
        heightMultiplier = ((double) displayHeight) / ((double) testedHeight);
    }

    public double getWidthMultiplier(){
        return widthMultiplier;
    }

    public double getHeightMultiplier(){
        return heightMultiplier;
    }
}
```

Or a code like this is violating that rule?

```
public class FirstActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    private int displayWidth;
    private int displayHeight;

    private double widthMultiplier;
    private double heightMultiplier;

    private int testedWidth = 1200;
    private int testedHeight = 1920;

    public void setDisplayCorrectedSizes(RelativeLayout relativeLayout){
        displayWidth = relativeLayout.getWidth();
        widthMultiplier = ((double) displayWidth) / ((double) testedWidth);

        displayHeight = relativeLayout.getHeight();
        heightMultiplier = ((double) displayHeight) / ((double) testedHeight);
        
        this.relativeLayout = relativeLayout;
    }

    public double getWidthMultiplier(){
        return widthMultiplier;
    }

    public double getHeightMultiplier(){
        return heightMultiplier;
    }
}
```

Or both of them are violating?

I just want to understand am I in a right way to understand it or not.

.......................................

Here is the whole code that I wanted to replace from view to ViewModel.

```
 void actionsForUISizesOptimizationProcess(){
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.rootLayoutSmallBoard);

       
        int displayWidth = relativeLayout2.getWidth();
        int displayHeight = relativeLayout2.getHeight();

        
        int testedWidth = 1200;
        double widthMultiplier = ((double) displayWidth) / ((double) testedWidth);
        int testedHeight = 1920;
        double heightMultiplier = ((double) displayHeight) / ((double) testedHeight);

//        firstActivityViewModel.setDisplayCorrectedSizes(relativeLayout2);
//        double widthMultiplier = firstActivityViewModel.getWidthMultiplier();
//        double heightMultiplier = firstActivityViewModel.getHeightMultiplier();

        if (limitOfOnWindowFocusChangedOperationForSmallBoard == 0) { /

            //Log.i("userTest2020", "display width = " + displayWidth + "\n" + "display height = " + displayHeight);

            int viewWidth;
            int viewHeight;

            viewWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tv10WidthSmallBoard);
            viewHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tv10HeightSmallBoard);

            tvSmallBoardResolutionInfoValue.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (viewWidth * widthMultiplier);
            tvSmallBoardResolutionInfoValue.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

            viewWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tv11WidthSmallBoard);
            viewHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tv11HeightSmallBoard);

            tvSmallBoardScoreValue.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (viewWidth * widthMultiplier);
            tvSmallBoardScoreValue.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

            viewWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.btn1WidthSmallBoard);
            viewHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.btn1HeightSmallBoard);

            btnSmallBoardGetTheResolutionInfo.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (viewWidth * widthMultiplier);
            btnSmallBoardGetTheResolutionInfo.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

            viewWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.btnNewRoundWidthSmallBoard);
            viewHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.btnNewRoundHeightSmallBoard);

            btnNewRoundSmallBoard.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (viewWidth * widthMultiplier);
            btnNewRoundSmallBoard.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

            ImageView ivBtnGreen = findViewById(R.id.ivNewRoundSmallBoard);
            viewWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.ivNewRoundWidthSmallBoard);
            viewHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.ivNewRoundHeightSmallBoard);

            ivBtnGreen.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (viewWidth * widthMultiplier);
            ivBtnGreen.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

           
            FrameLayout flNewBoard = findViewById(R.id.newRoundViewGroupSmallBoard);
            viewWidth = flNewBoard.getWidth();
            viewHeight = flNewBoard.getHeight();

            flNewBoard.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (viewWidth * widthMultiplier);
            flNewBoard.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

            FrameLayout flBiggerBoard = findViewById(R.id.biggerBoardViewGroupSmallBoard);
            viewWidth = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.BiggerBoardViewGroupSmallBoard);

            flBiggerBoard.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (viewWidth * widthMultiplier);

            viewHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.btnNextBoardHeightSmallBoard);

            btnNextBoardSmallBoard.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

            ImageView ivNextBoard = findViewById(R.id.ivNextBoardSmallBoard);
            viewHeight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.ivNextBoardHeightSmallBoard);

            ivNextBoard.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (viewHeight * heightMultiplier);

            limitOfOnWindowFocusChangedOperationForSmallBoard = 1; 
        }
    }
```

Why I thought that I must replace this code to ViewModel? See here https://android.jlelse.eu/mvvm-how-view-and-viewmodel-should-communicate-8a386ce1bb42 (The rule number one)
And why I can't figure out how to do it? Cause on the other hand there is another rule:  View model should never reference a view. If you do, then you'll get
memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, the second one is violating the rule while the first one isn't, but ideally, viewModel should never care about the view. Using Relative layout as an argument will be problematic while writing unit tests. Our aim should be to separate viewModel from view as much as possible. I would suggest rewriting your second approach like this

```html
public void setDisplayCorrectedSizes(int displayWidth, int displayHeight){
    widthMultiplier = ((double) displayWidth) / ((double) testedWidth);
    heightMultiplier = ((double) displayHeight) / ((double) testedHeight);
}
```

Another suggestion would be replace getter methods with observables that emit values for view to observe. I would rewrite your viewModel like this

```html
public class FirstActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private LiveData<Double> widthMultiplierLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
    private LiveData<Double> heightMultiplierLiveData = new MutableLiveData();
    
    private final int testedWidth = 1200;
    private final int testedHeight = 1920;

    public void setDisplayCorrectedSizes(int displayWidth, int displayHeight){
        double widthMultiplier = ((double) displayWidth) / ((double) testedWidth);
        double heightMultiplier = ((double) displayHeight) / ((double) testedHeight);
        
        widthMultiplierLiveData.value = widthMultiplier;
        heightMultiplierLiveData.value = heightMultiplier;
    }
}
```

Comment: "but ideally, viewModel should never care about the view. " I thought the same, but I found an article where was written this statement "View should not have any logic in it, not at all! Not even a simple if condition. All logic for the view happens in ViewModel." (the source of that statement see here https://android.jlelse.eu/mvvm-how-view-and-viewmodel-should-communicate-8a386ce1bb42)

Comment: I rewrote my question, added there the whole code from view which I wanted to replace to ViewModel, so you can understand why I decided to try to do replacement.

Comment: Well there is no right way to do this. I personally let the view handle view logics i.e changing the size. If you think about it, the view defines it sizes inside xml as well. I don't think managing view sizes should be delegated to viewModel. viewModel is responsible to update the state of view(states like loading, enabled, disabled, render data etc).  All this logic can live inside view class. Also as CommonsWare pointed out, CosntraintLayout would be more suitable to handle aspectRatio

Comment: Ahh, ok. I'm glad that I was near to the right way. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of avoiding memory leaks, your second `FirstActivityViewModel` is violating the rule. You have a Java field that holds a reference to the `RelativeLayout`. If `FirstActivity` gets destroyed and recreated due to a configuration change, until `setDisplayCorrectedSizes()` gets called by the second activity instance, your viewmodel is leaking the first activity instance.

More generally, I would avoid either of these approaches. A viewmodel is responsible for preparing the data to be rendered to the screen, but concerns about pixels and sizing is the job of the UI layer, not the viewmodel, IMHO.

Also, FWIW, you may wish to migrate to `ConstraintLayout`, as it is a more powerful and better maintained option than is `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I'm glad that I think the same. I just read a rule like this "View should not have any logic in it, not at all! Not even a simple if condition. All logic for the view happens in ViewModel." (the source link https://android.jlelse.eu/mvvm-how-view-and-viewmodel-should-communicate-8a386ce1bb42)  And that's why I thought to try to replace this code (which I showed in my question)  from View to ViewModel. I'll rewrite my question by adding the left code that I wanted to replace from View to ViewModel.

Comment: I rewrote my question